# Polymer Paper-Slider not draggable

Tags: html, css, slider, polymer

I am using the polymer paper-slider in my application, however, it always stays stuck in the initial position and does not drag on user action. The progress bar is also not visible. It looks like the following at the moment :

[image]

I am using the following code for this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Page 2</title>

  <meta name="viewport" 
  content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
  </script>

  <link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="post-card.html">
  <link rel="import" href="components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">


  <style shim-shadowdom>
  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
  }
  core-header-panel {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
  }
  paper-slider{
    width:800px;
  }

  core-toolbar {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: white;
  }
      section {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    section > div {
      padding: 14px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

  #tabs {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  paper-button[raised].colored {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    }


    .slider-markers, #sliderBar, #sliderKnob {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
    paper-slider::shadow #sliderKnobInner
    {
      background-color: #0f9d58;
    }
    paper-slider::shadow #sliderKnobInner::before
    {
        background-color: #0f9d58;
    }
    paper-slider::shadow #sliderBar::shadow #activeProgress {
      background-color: #0f9d58;
    }





  @media (min-width: 481px) {
    #tabs {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .container {
      width: 400px;
    }
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body fullbleed vertical layout unresolved>

  <core-header-panel flex mode="normal">

    <core-toolbar>
<span flex>Flow</span>
    </core-toolbar>

    <div class="container" layout vertical center>

      <post-card>
        <img width="70" height="70" 
        src="../images/venturimeter.jpg">
        <h2>Venturimeter</h2>
        <br/>        
          <div>In order to</div>
          <br/><br/>
    <paper-slider pin value="50"></paper-slider>
      <br/><br/>
      </post-card>

      <paper-button span raised class="colored" onclick="window.open('Page3.html','_parent');" layout center horizontal>Next</paper-button>




  </core-header-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

What is the mistake I am making here? How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: there is nothing i can see in this code that would stop it from being draggable.  i copied it into a plunker and everything seems to work fine with no changes. only thing is i didn't have the code for post-card.html which i assumed was just styling wrapping a <content></content>. http://plnkr.co/edit/fh81SVHbpW7LkcHRu1QU?p=preview

Comment: Yes the post-card.html is just to add a white card like background so it shouldn't affect the working of this.